# uib-popover does not show in ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I'm trying to include a uib-popover inside of an ag-grid cell. However, the popover is getting cut off (by the grid's overflow settings). What is the best way to make this work?

Here is the code that sets up the grid:

```
function _setGridOptions() {

    $ctrl.agGridOptions = {
        suppressHorizontalScroll: true,
        suppressColumnVirtualization: true,
        angularCompileRows: true,
        rowHeight: 64,
        columnDefs: [
            {headerName: "", width: 30, checkboxSelection: true, suppressSorting: true, suppressMenu: true, pinned: true},
            {headerName: "Sender", field: "submitterName", tooltipField: "submitterName", cellClass: "sender_name"},
            {headerName: "Package", field: "packageName", tooltipField: "packageName"},
            {headerName: "Document", cellRenderer: $ctrl._documentNameRenderer},
            {headerName: "Document Status", cellRenderer: $ctrl._stateRenderer},
            {headerName: "Recording Date", cellRenderer: $ctrl._recordingDateRenderer},
            {headerName: "", template: '<div style="height: 40px;"></div><div uib-popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="\'mouseenter\'">hover</div>'}
        ],
        onGridSizeChanged: function () {
            $ctrl.agGridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
        },
        onGridReady: function (param) {
            $ctrl.agGridOptions.api = param.api;
            if ($ctrl.search_results) {
                $ctrl.agGridOptions.api.setRowData($ctrl.search_results);
                $ctrl.agGridOptions.api.doLayout();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And this is what it looks like when you hover over the div...
[image: uib popover is cut off]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A co-worker pointed me to the solution...
All you have to do is add 'popover-append-to-body="true"'
This will attach the popover to the body tag instead of the parent, so that the overflow settings do not affect it.